# how to reduce quantity using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

has an error (An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.)

```
mycmd.Connection = myconnection.open
Dim dami As Integer = quantityt.Text
mycmd.CommandText = "Update inventory set total_quantity=total_quantity-'" & dami & "'  where item_code='" & itemcodet.Text & "'"
mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("stocks decrease!!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Noticed..")
myconnection.close()
```

Comment: DO NOT concatenate strings to build Sql queries. Use parameters. Your code risks SQL injection which can wreck your database.

Comment: Connection objects need to not only be closed but disposed. A Using...End Using block will take care of closing and disposing even if there is an error.

Comment: If you put up a MessageBox before your connection is closed, the user could have gone to lunch and the connection is left flapping in the breeze waiting for the OK button to be clicked.

Comment: What line in your code causes the error?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with following line

```
      mycmd.CommandText = "Update inventory set total_quantity=total_quantity-'" & dami & "'  where item_code='" & itemcodet.Text & "'"
```

should be

```
      mycmd.CommandText = "Update inventory set total_quantity=total_quantity-" & dami & "  where item_code='" & itemcodet.Text & "'"
```

dont use apostrophe ' when counting with integer.. apostrophes use only in case of string

Comment: This fixes the immediate problem, but it's lousy advice. Teach the user to use parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I used the SQL server provider for demonstration. Change to whatever database you are using. Check the actual data types of your fields in your database. Open the connection at the last minute. See my comment about Using blocks.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Using myconnection As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using mycmd As New SqlCommand("Update inventory set total_quantity = total_quantity - @dami where item_code = @itemCode;", myconnection)
            mycmd.Parameters.Add("@dami", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(quantityt.Text)
            mycmd.Parameters.Add("@itemCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = itemcodet.Text
            myconnection.Open()
            mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
    MsgBox("stocks decrease!!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Noticed..")
End Sub
```